# How can this statue on Level 23 of the "Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage" adventure be destroyed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, published-adventures, counterspelling, waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage

On page 290 of the adventure *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage* ([area 1 of Level 23](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/mad-wizards-lair#HalasterStatue)), there exists a [statue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/mad-wizards-lair#HalasterStatue) with the following description:

> Anytime a creature other than Halaster tries to cast a spell in this room, the statue's arms animate and perform the quick series of somatic gestures needed to cast [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell). After casting its spell, the statue reverts to its inanimate state until triggered again. The counterspell attempt succeeds automatically. The statue is a Large object with AC 17, 50 hit points, and immunity to all damage except force damage.

Given the following facts:

> - Only force damage can damage the statue, so any weapon attacks are useless
>  - No spells can be cast to damage the statue (spells are instantly counterspelled at 100% rate of success, and the statue is not limited to one reaction per round)

Is it impossible to destroy the statue? Or is there any way that I missed?

Comment: Destroying the statue isn't what you want to do, you want to shrink it and carry it around with you. That's an awesome magical item.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Cast the spell outside the room

For example,
*Mordenkainen's Sword* and *Spiritual Weapon*
both [can be moved](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201498/can-you-use-your-bonus-action-to-move-but-not-attack-with-a-spiritual-weapon) and have a duration of one minute. You can cast them outside the room, move them in, and destroy the statue with them. Once they already are cast, *counterspell* does nothing to stop them.

Depending on the layout of the room and what kind of vision the statue has (if that is stated) you can also try to cast the spells while you are invisible or behind full cover or further away than 60 feet: *counterspell* can only target a creature you can see within 60 feet.

Answer (score 18):

[Groody's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/203464/28402) points out that there are some spells that can get around the automatic counterspell problem, but here's some other solutions...

### Use magical items that deal force damage

There's a variety of magical items available that can be used to deal force damage without involving any counterable spellcasting. The one that seems most immediately suitable for the job of destroying the statue is the *[sphere of annihilation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4759-sphere-of-annihilation)*, though that's difficult to transport if you don't have one immediately available; a non-exhaustive search of the D&D Beyond database flags up some more options such as the *[staff of striking](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4765-staff-of-striking)*, *[staff of power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4764-staff-of-power)*, *[ring of the ram](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4734-ring-of-the-ram)*, *[bead of force](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4583-bead-of-force)*... I'm sure there are others.

### Use character options that deal force damage

Some character options grant access to abilities that deal force damage without using spells. The ones I could quickly find/remember:

- Psi Warrior fighters have [Psionic Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#PsionicPower-2996139), which can deal extra force damage when they hit something with a weapon attack.
- Way of the Astral Self monks have [Arms of the Astral Self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#ArmsoftheAstralSelf-2992431), which enables them to deal force damage with their unarmed strikes.
- Amethyst [gem dragonborn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/16-dragonborn#GemDragonborn) have the ability to deal force damage with their breath weapon.

Comment: Shoot it with Eldritch Blast from 70 feet away.  counterspell has a range of 60'

Answer (score 4):

Some alternative ideas:

- Cover it with a tarp, it won't have line of effect so it can't counterspell
- Shackle or tie it's hands, it should not be able to perform the somatic components. It's up to the DM if this actually stops it, or if it can break free.
- Move it to another room, from the wording the statue won't do anything if it's not in the room. Might be hard without magic but maybe the floor can be destroyed?
- Overwhelm it. More DM discretion, as the statue doesn't technically have or use actions, but surely casting Counterspell takes some amount of time, and if you managed to cast 10 spells in a round it can't do the somatic components to cast it ten times

Answer (score -4):

I'm curious if this is a player asking or a DM.  I want to assume it is the DM.  And I think it isn't always important to know how.

This room has a weird shape that nullifies a lot of range questions.  As the statue is in that weird southern alcove.  I'm not sure off hand if there is force aoe damage spells.  That could be something.  It cant see someone casting from the SE or SW and letting the damage splash to it.

Melee users with force damage are solid options.

As much as I hate to recommend, casting and letting your familiar deliver the force spells would work... as simple as having Eldritch Blast.
I think finding out how is more of the puzzle than if.  Are there ways your party can might be a big question.